# Why isn't converting from an NFA to a DFA working?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I am just beginning to learn computation theory. I wrote up a non-deterministic finite automata that accepts strings that contain the substring "abba":

[image: My NFA]

I tried to convert it to a DFA by putting together sets of states in the NFA to be states of the DFA:[image: My DFA]

However, I just realized that my DFA doesn't accept strings such as "abbaa" that do not end in "abba." That means that my methodology was wrong. Why? I thought it would make sense to combine states of the NFA to make states of the DFA.

Comment: First, make sure the NFA works (it only accepts strings that **end** with "abba")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your methodology for creating the DFA from the NFA is fine. The problem is that you started with the wrong NFA (you'll notice that your NFA doesn't accept abbaa either). Try this one instead:
[image]

Comment: How could I say that "NFA doesn't accept abbaa either" since from state 5 transition for a is not defined we remain at state 5 itself and it is a final state?

Comment: @user5507, if a transition for a symbol is undefined at a particular state, the automata doesn't stay in that state if it sees that symbol, it changes to "no state". I.e. if there's no transition, it gets stuck/automatically rejects.

Comment: @user5507 It is find to define the final state as "if transition undefined stay accepted", but then, your transitions from `{1,2,5}` should always contains a `5`.